# Parser in C doesn't store values in a array

Tags: arrays, c, parsing, strtok

I write a parser in C to parse a file that describe a graph, with vertex and edges, the graph file looks like this :

```
c FILE: graph_test
c
c SOURCE: generator
c 
p edge 10 12
e 1 2
e 2 3
e 6 2
```

the "c" lines correspond to comments (must be ignored), the "p" line describe the number of nodes and the number of Edges, and the nbEdges "e" following lines describe the edges between the two nodes.

I use strtok() to split the string to get only the values that interest me, but when I try to store the values into a array `int edges[nb_adges][2]`, the array is filled with wrong valued

Here's the entire code
("aretes" = edges, and "sommets" : nodes)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAILLE_MAX 1000

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("\n[UTILISATION] : ./parseur chemin_fichier\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* nom_fichier = argv[1];
    FILE* fichier;

    //Ouverture en lecture
    fichier = fopen(nom_fichier,"r");
    if(fichier == NULL) {
        printf("\nImpossible d'ouvrir le fichier '%s'\n", nom_fichier);
        exit(2);
    }

    char ligne[TAILLE_MAX];
    int nb_sommets = 0;
    int nb_aretes = 0;
    int aretes[nb_aretes][2];

    //On lit chaque ligne du fichier
    int i;
    while(fgets(ligne, TAILLE_MAX, fichier) != NULL) {
        //Si la ligne commence par "c" c'est un commentaire on l'ignore
        if(ligne[0] == 'c') {
            continue;
        }
        //Si la ligne commence par "p" c'est la ligne qui contient le nombre de sommets et de aretes
        if(ligne[0] == 'p') {
            i = 0;
            char* tmp = strtok(ligne, " ");
            while(tmp != NULL) {
                if(i == 2) {
                    nb_sommets = atoi(tmp);
                }
                if(i == 3) {
                    nb_aretes = atoi(tmp);
                }
                tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }

        //Si la ligne commence par "e" on récupère les aretes
        if(ligne[0] == 'e') {
            char* tmp = strtok(ligne, " ");
            int j = 0;
            while(tmp != NULL) {
                if(j == 1) {
                    aretes[i][0] = atoi(tmp);
                }
                if(j == 2) {
                    aretes[i][1] = atoi(tmp);
                }
                printf("tmp : %s\n",tmp);
                tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    printf("\nNombre de sommets : %d\n", nb_sommets);
    printf("Nombre d'aretes : %d\n", nb_aretes);
    printf("Liste des aretes :\n");

    //On affiche toutes les aretes
    for(int i = 0; i < nb_aretes; i++) {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", aretes[i][0], aretes[i][1]);
    }

    //On ferme le fichier
    fclose(fichier);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to print the value of tmp in the 'e' loop, it display the correct value of nodes, but the array `int edges[nb_edges][2]` is filled with stranges values

```
> Execution 
List of edges :
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
6 -> 2
8 -> 3
3473509 -> 52
8 -> 7
9 -> 4
5 -> 6
7 -> 9
10 -> 1
1 -> 7
5 -> 4
```

Comment: You never reset `i` at the start of the `while` loop. Remove `int i = 0;` Then, put `int i = 2;` _after_ the `while`. That is the simplest fix. You _could_ clean that up with `0` if you also changed to `if (i == 1)` and `if (i == 2)` respectively. For `p`, you have to skip the `"edge"` string from `p edge`

Comment: which`while` ? there is 3 of them ?

Comment: I don't know if your line is literally fixed with `p edge` each time or you can have (e.g.) `p foo` and `p bar` (i.e. `p <name>`. If the latter, you may want to save the name value

Comment: yes the line is always `p edge x y`, where x and y are int numbers

Comment: Okay, to be more clear, move it to after `if(line[0] == 'p') {`. That's the best placement. The `while` _was_ the outer one: `while(fgets`

Comment: Okay, thanks to your help I menaged to progress, now there are only one value that is cursed.
I edited the code and the execution, but the 5th value is still buged

Comment: _Side note:_ I was on mobile, so I couldn't do a complete answer. I've noticed other bugs. I'm back at my desk, so I'll do a complete answer.

Comment: Please read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266581/775806).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my top comments ...

This:

```
int nb_aretes = 0;
int aretes[nb_aretes][2];
```

This is [effectively]:

```
int aretes[0][2];
```

That's because the size is *fixed* when the declaration occurs. It does *not* increase if `nb_aretes` is increased subsequently.

We need a fixed size array (e.g.):

```
#define ARETES_MAX 10000
int aretes[ARETES_MAX][2];
```

The data file does *not* match up. The `p` line says 15 edges but there are only 3 `e` lines.

---

Although, I studied French [for four years, 40 years ago], I ran your code through google translate. So, some of this may be from that.

I changed the code to ignore the `p` line for `nb_edges` and to just count the `e` lines:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1000                   // max line size
#define EDGES_MAX 10000                 // max number of edges/nodes

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("\n[USAGE]: ./parser file_path\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *file_name = argv[1];
    FILE *file;

    // Open for reading
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("\nCould not open file '%s'\n", file_name);
        exit(2);
    }

    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int nb_vertices = 0;

// NOTE/BUG: this produces [effectively]
    int nb_edges = 0;
#if 0
    int edges[nb_edges][2];
#else
    int counted_edges = 0;
    int edges[EDGES_MAX][2];
#endif

    // We read each line of the file
    int i;

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, file) != NULL) {
        // If the line begins with "c" it is a comment, we ignore it
        if (line[0] == 'c') {
            continue;
        }

        // If the line begins with "p" this is the line that contains the
        // number of vertices and edges
        if (line[0] == 'p') {
            i = 0;
            char *tmp = strtok(line, " ");

            while (tmp != NULL) {
                if (i == 2) {
                    nb_vertices = atoi(tmp);
                }
                if (i == 3) {
// NOTE/BUG: in the data file, this does _not_ match the number of "e" lines
                    nb_edges = atoi(tmp);
// NOTE/BUG: this is flagged by the compiler with -Wall
// NOTE/BUG: using [2] is UB (undefined behavior) because the max index can be
// is 1
#if 0
                    edges[nb_edges][2];
#endif
                }
                tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // If the line begins with "e" we retrieve the edges
        if (line[0] == 'e') {
            char *tmp = strtok(line, " ");
            int j = 0;

            while (tmp != NULL) {
                if (j == 1) {
#if 0
                    edges[i][0] = atoi(tmp);
#else
                    edges[counted_edges][0] = atoi(tmp);
#endif
                }
                if (j == 2) {
#if 0
                    edges[i][1] = atoi(tmp);
#else
                    edges[counted_edges][1] = atoi(tmp);
#endif
                }
                printf("tmp: %s\n", tmp);
                tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                j++;
            }
#if 0
            i++;
#else
            ++counted_edges;
#endif
            continue;
        }
    }

    printf("\nNumber of vertices: %d\n", nb_vertices);
    printf("Number of edges: %d (expected)\n", nb_edges);
    printf("Number of edges: %d (calculated)\n", counted_edges);
    printf("List of edges:\n");

    // We display all the edges
#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < nb_edges; i++) {
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < counted_edges; i++) {
#endif
        printf("%d -> %d\n", edges[i][0], edges[i][1]);
    }

    // We close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

I used your sample input:

```
c FILE: graph_test
c
c SOURCE: generator
c
p edge 10 12
e 1 2
e 2 3
e 6 2
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
tmp: e
tmp: 1
tmp: 2

tmp: e
tmp: 2
tmp: 3

tmp: e
tmp: 6
tmp: 2

Number of vertices: 10
Number of edges: 12 (expected)
Number of edges: 3 (calculated)
List of edges:
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
6 -> 2
```

---

I think the code can be simplified. There is too much replication of `strtok` calls under each `if` statement.

Better to have a loop that splits the line before deciding on the command to process.

And, a `switch/case` seems better than the `if` statements.

Here's how I would clean things up:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1000                   // max line size
#define EDGES_MAX 10000                 // max number of edges/nodes
#if 1
#define MAX_TOKENS  10                  // max tokens per line
#endif

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("\n[USAGE]: ./parser file_path\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *file_name = argv[1];
    FILE *file;

    // Open for reading
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("\nCould not open file '%s'\n", file_name);
        exit(2);
    }

    char line[MAX_LINE];
    char saved_line[MAX_LINE];

    int nb_vertices = 0;
    int nb_edges = 0;
    int counted_edges = 0;
    int edges[EDGES_MAX][2];

    // We read each line of the file

#if 1
    int ntokens;
    char *tokens[MAX_TOKENS + 1];
#endif

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, file) != NULL) {
        // If the line begins with "c" [or "#"] it is a comment, we ignore it
        if (line[0] == 'c')
            continue;
#if 1
        if (line[0] == '#')
            continue;
#endif

        // split line into tokens
#if 1
        // copy in case of error
        strcpy(saved_line,line);

        char *tok = strtok(line," \n");
        for (ntokens = 0;  ntokens < MAX_TOKENS;  ++ntokens) {
            if (tok == NULL)
                break;
            tokens[ntokens] = tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        }
        tokens[ntokens] = NULL;

        // ignore blank lines
        if (ntokens == 0)
            continue;
#endif

        switch (line[0]) {
        case 'p':
            // If the line begins with "p" this is the line that contains the
            // number of vertices and edges
            if (ntokens != 4) {
                printf("bad p line -- ntokens=%d %s",ntokens,saved_line);
                exit(1);
            }

            nb_vertices = atoi(tokens[2]);
            nb_edges = atoi(tokens[3]);
            break;

        case 'e':
            // If the line begins with "e" we retrieve the edges
            if (ntokens != 3) {
                printf("bad e line -- ntokens=%d %s",ntokens,saved_line);
                exit(1);
            }

            edges[counted_edges][0] = atoi(tokens[1]);
            edges[counted_edges][1] = atoi(tokens[2]);
            ++counted_edges;
            break;

        default:
            printf("unknown command -- %s",saved_line);
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nNumber of vertices: %d\n", nb_vertices);
    printf("Number of edges: %d (expected)\n", nb_edges);
    printf("Number of edges: %d (calculated)\n", counted_edges);
    printf("List of edges:\n");

    // We display all the edges
    for (int i = 0; i < counted_edges; i++)
        printf("%d -> %d\n", edges[i][0], edges[i][1]);

    // We close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I did not do the following in the code above.

But, if the intention was that there is only *one* `p` line at the top of the file, we *could* use the:

```
int aretes[nb_aretes][2];
```

But, we'd have to parse the `p` line above that definition in a separate block. Then, `nb_aretes` would be set correctly [dynamically] *before* we see the definition.

Comment: Thanks for your help, explantation and translation !

Comment: Took some interpretation: google translated `continue;` as `keep on going;` :-)